# Splitting a Polyline at intersections

Tags: qgis, line, road

How can I split a road network into different links splitting at intersections??
The whole network is in one single layer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use `Split lines by lines` tool, and use the same file as input layer and split layer, as you can see below:

[image]

You can find the tool from `Processing toolbox -> QGIS Geoalgorithms -> Vector Overlay tools -> Split lines by lines`

Here is the tool in the Processing Menu:

[image]

Before running the tool:

[image]

After running the tool:

[image]

**Update for QGIS 3.x**

Although the tool has the same name in `SAGA -> Vector line tools`, it has a different name in QGIS 3.x. The new name is `Split with lines` located under `Processing tools -> Vector overlay -> Split with lines`:

[image]

Comment: under the Vector Overlay tools there is no such option of "split lines with lines". I am using QGIS 2.10.1 Pisa. Can you help me with that.

Comment: I updated my answer. I am using QGIS 2.14.15 in case yours is different. You need to update QGIS to the latest release.

Comment: @AMALDATTA - At the bottom of the _Processing Toolbox_, make sure you are using the `Advanced interface` and not the `Simplified interface`. This algorithm was available since QGIS 2.8 :)

Comment: @Joseph Thank you very much for pointing that, I completely forget this point, as I am always using Advanced interface.

Comment: @ahmadhanb - Most welcome! Although it is just a guess since the OP is using a fairly old version :)

Comment: @Joseph Thank you very much. It worked. But, I have a few instances where it dint. Can I know what might be the reasons for it?? from what i can observe, it dint work in the places where "T" intersections were formed.

Comment: @AMALDATTA - It may depend on how those intersections look. I suggest you accept this answer (by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side) to show your initial question has been solved and then ask a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with your details and screenshots :)