# Looking for a QGIS 3.12 equivalent to Trim in ArcMap

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, line

I have a polygon layer with one rectangle. I have created a second polygon layer from a buffer on the rectangle. Therefore 2 differently sized rectangles that are identical in proportions but the smaller one exists completely inside the larger one.

I have lines that cross both rectangles, like Lat Long graticles.

I'd like to get rid of the portions of the lines that are inside the smaller rectangle and the portions of the lines that are outside the larger rectangle leaving just ticks that are the length of the gap between the two rectangle layers.

I don't care if it takes a number of steps, I'd just like to get it done.

I've thought of something that might be the direction of a solution but I'm not sure how to proceed with it. Convert both polygons to lines. Cut the "lat long" lines at the intersections with these "lines from rectangles", then delete the inner and outer leaving just the segments between the two rectangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can circumvent the outer polygon completely.

Use a combination of:

1. The **clip** geoprocessing tool
2. The [**extend line**](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#extend-lines) tool
3. The **difference** geoprocessing tool

Clip your graticule lines with the rectangle you want, then use the extend lines tool on the resulting clipped lines by the distance you want at each ends. Then pass the layers through the difference tool.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [QAD plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qad/) which has tools like Trim, Extend, and others, similar to what you can find in ArcMap editing tools. If you have experience with AutoCAD software, this plugin is quite similar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be able to do what I'm looking for: Splitting a Polyline at Intersections ([Splitting a Polyline at intersections](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247013/splitting-a-polyline-at-intersections))