# Cutting OSM roads in sections using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I define a section by a part of a road that has no intersection. See image below:
[image]

I'd like to extract all sections from all the roads of my PostGIS database. This GIS database was created with osm2pgsl:

```
               List of relations
 Schema |        Name        | Type  |  Owner
--------+--------------------+-------+----------
 public | geography_columns  | view  | postgres
 public | geometry_columns   | table | gis
 public | planet_osm_line    | table | postgres
 public | planet_osm_nodes   | table | postgres
 public | planet_osm_point   | table | postgres
 public | planet_osm_polygon | table | postgres
 public | planet_osm_rels    | table | postgres
 public | planet_osm_roads   | table | postgres
 public | planet_osm_ways    | table | postgres
 public | spatial_ref_sys    | table | gis
(10 rows)
```

I've read [an interesting post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20835/identifying-road-intersections-using-postgis) about detecting the intersections but I can't figure out how to create a table with sections.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](http://blog.loudhush.ro/2011/10/using-pgrouting-on-osm-database.html) is a good way to resolve this problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION compute_network() RETURNS text as $$
DECLARE
streetRecord record;
pointIndex integer;
geomFragment record;
BEGIN
FOR streetRecord in select way, osm_id, name from planet_osm_line where highway is not null LOOP
 FOR pointIndex in 1..ST_NPoints(streetRecord.way)-1 LOOP
  select st_makeline(st_pointn(streetRecord.way, pointIndex), st_pointn(streetRecord.way, pointIndex+1)) as way into geomFragment;
  insert into network(osm_id, name, the_geom, length) values(streetRecord.osm_id, streetRecord.name, geomFragment.way, st_length(geomFragment.way));
 END LOOP;
END LOOP;
return 'Done';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the well referenced software OSM2PO which will split all the OSM ways into distinct road sections : you can check http://osm2po.de . Produced road sections (links) can be directly imported into psql for routing.

Comment: thx, I'm checking this out.

Comment: the main problem about osm2po is that it is neither open source nor well documented.