# Identifying points on the intersection of three roads in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection, road

I have two tables `point` and `roads` in my PostgreSQL 9.5 database. Some of the points lie on the intersections of three roads (line segments). The sample scenario is as follows:

[image: sample scenario]

I want to identify all such points that lie on the intersection of three roads. I came across [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20835/identifying-road-intersections-using-postgis) question on GIS-SE, but the code returned me all points on the intersections of individual line segments which is not desired. Can someone suggest me how do I identify the points that lie on the intersection of three segments (street crossing) only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of a join on ST_Intersects, where you put the count of road IDs in a where clause, and group by node_id.

```
SELECT count(road_id) as cnt, node_id
  FROM nodes n
    INNER JOIN roads r ON ST_Intersects(n.geom, r.geom)
  GROUP BY node_id
  HAVING count(road_id) = 3;
```

Intersecting lines and points can be problematic, depending on rounding/precision issues, so you might need to combine this with [ST_SnapToGrid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html), ie, snap both the points and lines to the same precision grid.

**EDIT:** As @ziggy has pointed out, you need to use HAVING not WHERE when using aggregates as a condition.

This is untested, so if you could provide some sample data, it would help.

Comment: untested comment here but shouldnt you use the having clause instead of the agg function in the where clause?

Comment: @ziggy, probably, yes.

Comment: Tested comment: Thanks @JohnPowellakaBarça for your help. You need to place "Group by" clause before "Having" clause for this query to work. I was getting syntax error with this version of your query. I fixed it and it seems to be giving me points as desired.

Comment: Uf, need more coffee. Edited question. Please accept it, if it works, even if you deserve half the credit for debugginng it :-)

Comment: I had coffee with me when I fixed it ;) Accepted.