# Detecting overshoot lines in road network (flyovers, over/underpasses) in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, network

I'd like to know a way to detect overshoot lines (such as flyovers, over/underpasses) in road network through queries in `PostGIS` to validate topological connections.

This is a sample network:

```
CREATE TABLE net (id integer, geom geometry(MultiLineString, 4326));
INSERT INTO net (id, geom)
VALUES (1,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.63964778201967 36.58031552554121,136.64078637948796 36.57968013023401,136.6414207216891 36.579313967665655,136.64203092428795 36.578959650067986,136.6428838673968 36.57843301697034,136.6438347098042 36.577844992552514))', 4326)),
       (2,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.64039880046448 36.57933335255234,136.64078637948796 36.57968013023401,136.64119407544638 36.580076445271914,136.64165541506554 36.58051798901414))', 4326)),
       (3,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.64039880046448 36.57933335255234,136.64044439789086 36.578869185464725))', 4326)),
       (4,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.6409003730539 36.57873995108804,136.6414207216891 36.579313967665655,136.64222404380473 36.580108753416425))', 4326)),
       (5,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.6416232292288 36.57843409435816,136.64203092428795 36.578959650067986))', 4326)),
       (6,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.64203092428795 36.578959650067986,136.64244666738 36.57935489221467,136.64283290461503 36.57974259264671))', 4326)),
       (7,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.64250969906357 36.57802376968141,136.6428838673968 36.57843301697034,136.64326608196427 36.578854108330574))', 4326)),
       (8,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.64364829653186 36.577513284810436,136.6438347098042 36.577844992552514))', 4326)),
       (9,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.6438347098042 36.577844992552514,136.64412438862985 36.57833070559775))', 4326));
```

As illustrated in the following image, this network has 9 lines where line 2, 4 and 7 do not topologically connected to line 1.
I need to generate points and export it as a new table at the corossing points of those links as shown in the right-hand side figure.

I tried to search for the solutions but could not find so far.

[image]

Actually I posted a similar question [Detecting overshoot lines in road network (flyovers, over/underpasses) in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/433102/detecting-overshoot-lines-in-road-network-flyovers-over-underpasses-in-qgis) but I would like to be able to manipulate it in `PostGIS` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*pgRouting* has a comprehensive set of functions to address most of the issues you are facing, with regards to your series of questions about network topologies:

- [Merging lines of which ends are not connected but close in PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/433100/merging-lines-of-which-ends-are-not-connected-but-close-in-postgis)
- [Simplifying road network with PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/432988/simplifying-road-network-with-postgis)

I'll try to answer them all with a set of queries to create a routable network for most input lineworks.

---

1. **Dump your `MultiLineString`s:**

   A proper topology should consist of simple `LineString`s - for *pgRouting* it is mandatory:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE <network_simple> AS (
     SELECT
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
       id AS old_id,
       dmp.path[1] AS old_id_seq,
       <attribute_1>,
       ...
       dmp.geom::GEOMETRY(LINESTRING, 4326) AS geom
     FROM
       <network>,
       LATERAL ST_Dump(geom) AS dmp
   );

   ALTER TABLE
     <network_simple>
     ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)
   ;
   ```
2. **Create a *noded* network:**

   Split the resulting linework at intersections:

   ```
   SELECT
     pgr_nodeNetwork(
       '<network_simple>',
       0.000001,
       'id',
       'geom'
     )
   ;
   ```
3. **Create a *pgRouting* topology:**

   Add `source/target` information to your `<network_simple>_noded` table:

   ```
   SELECT
     pgr_createTopology(
       '<network_simple>_noded',
       0.000005,
       'geom',
       'id',
       'source',
       'target'
     )
   ;
   ```

---

**Notes:**

- the resulting network topology in `<network_simple>_noded` maintains a reference to `<network_simple>` via `<network_simple>_noded.old_id = <network_simple>.id`
- the gap issue is addressed by providing the `tolerance` parameter in `pgr_createTopology`; while it *does not alter the geometries*, it treats those within distance of the given `tolerance` as connected
- while it is possible to brute force a (interconnected) line merge (i.e. simplification) and noding operation via

  ```
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
    dmp.geom
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        ST_Node(ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(geom))) AS geom
      FROM
        <network>
    ) AS nu,
    LATERAL ST_Dump(nu.geom) AS dmp
  ;
  ```

  you'd loose all (unique) references to your `<network>` table: if you are okay with that, just execute **3.** from above afterwards
- if you were to run a graph contraction operation (`pgr_contraction`) on the `<network_simple>_noded`, you would likely solve the gaps and line merge issues, but you have to be aware that this algorithm is meant for edge/vertex compression, and the resulting topology would likely not *look* like your input network due to altered edges

Comment: It helps me a lot. One thing is that I do not need to split flyover links when those links do not intersect with other links in actual situation (I haven't tried yet but `2. Create a noded network` splits all links at all intersections, isn't it? Sorry if I misunderstood).

After simplifing and merging all links, I want to check location of those remaining overshoot links (i.e., extracting those links or generating points at intersections) so that I can check whether those links are grade-separated or not in real road network.

Sorry if my explanation is not sufficient.

Comment: @HSJ gotcha. It sounded like you wanted a fully noded network. If at this point only detection is what you need, see dr_jts's answer.

Comment: I am trying to understand how I can utilize your suggestions but have two quwstions:

#1. `pgr_contraction` returns a table with columns `type, id, contracted_vertices, source, target, cost` but it doesn't contain `geom`. How to extract the contracted network in shp file from this?

#2. silimar to #1. `pgr_createTopology` returns `<network>_noded_vertices_pgr` but it is just a set of nodes with geom.  I do not understand how to use this `pgRouting topology` for my usage (export the result into shp file).

Comment: I realized the above two questions are out of the original scope. Please ignore it. I will make a new post.if necessary.

Comment: @HSJ the actual utilization of `pgr_contraction` is indeed rather complex - there is a guide in the docs, though. The `<network_simple>_noded` table holds your edges, you can export them.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is as in your title, you just want to detect the lines intersected by line 1 (but not the ones just touching it) :

```
SELECT a.*
FROM net a, net b
WHERE a.id != 1 AND b.id = 1 AND ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
   AND ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom) IS NOT TRUE
```

If you want to generate points on theses intersections as shown in your image, you have to extract a point (`ST_CollectionExtract(geom,1)`) from the intersection of the lines (`ST_Intersection(line1,line2)`)

```
SELECT ST_CollectionExtract(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom),1) as geom
FROM net a, net b
WHERE a.id != 1 AND b.id = 1 AND ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
   AND ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom) IS NOT TRUE
```

Comment: It works well in the network that I posted as an example, but the actual network that I am using in my research contains dozens of flyovers...

Comment: And so ? It should work for all the flyovers. But clearly, @dr_jts' answer is more synthetic and efficient

Answer (score 3):

`ST_Crosses` tests if two lines cross rather than touch.  This can be run to check all unordered pairs using a "triangle join".  The intersection point is computed with `ST_Intersection`.

```
WITH data(id, geom) AS (VALUES
  (1,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.63964778201967 36.58031552554121,136.64078637948796 36.57968013023401,136.6414207216891 36.579313967665655,136.64203092428795 36.578959650067986,136.6428838673968 36.57843301697034,136.6438347098042 36.577844992552514))', 4326)),
  (2,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.64039880046448 36.57933335255234,136.64078637948796 36.57968013023401,136.64119407544638 36.580076445271914,136.64165541506554 36.58051798901414))', 4326)),
  (3,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.64039880046448 36.57933335255234,136.64044439789086 36.578869185464725))', 4326)),
  (4,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.6409003730539 36.57873995108804,136.6414207216891 36.579313967665655,136.64222404380473 36.580108753416425))', 4326)),
  (5,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.6416232292288 36.57843409435816,136.64203092428795 36.578959650067986))', 4326)),
  (6,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.64203092428795 36.578959650067986,136.64244666738 36.57935489221467,136.64283290461503 36.57974259264671))', 4326)),
  (7,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.64250969906357 36.57802376968141,136.6428838673968 36.57843301697034,136.64326608196427 36.578854108330574))', 4326)),
  (8,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.64364829653186 36.577513284810436,136.6438347098042 36.577844992552514))', 4326)),
  (9,ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((136.6438347098042 36.577844992552514,136.64412438862985 36.57833070559775))', 4326))
)
SELECT a.id, b.id, ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) AS geom 
FROM data a
JOIN data b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
WHERE a.id < b.id AND ST_Crosses(a.geom, b.geom);
```

See also this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/431247/14766